# MySQL Group By Consecutive Rows

Tags: mysql

I have a feed application that I am trying to group results from consecutively. 
My table looks like this:

```
    postid | posttype | target | action     |        date         | title      | content
      1    |  userid  |  NULL  | upgrade    | 0000-01-00 00:00:00 | Upgraded 1 | exmple
      1    |  userid  |  NULL  | upgrade    | 0000-01-00 00:00:01 | Upgraded 2 | exmple
      1    |  userid  |  NULL  | downgrade  | 0000-01-00 00:00:02 | Downgraded | exmple
      1    |  userid  |  NULL  | upgrade    | 0000-01-00 00:00:03 | Upgraded   | exmple
```

What I would like the outcome to be is:

```
    postid | posttype | target | action     |        date         | title      | content
      1    |  userid  |  NULL  | upgrade    | 0000-01-00 00:00:01 | Upgrade 1  | exmple,exmple
      1    |  userid  |  NULL  | downgrade  | 0000-01-00 00:00:02 | Downgraded | exmple
      1    |  userid  |  NULL  | upgrade    | 0000-01-00 00:00:03 | Upgraded   | exmple
```

So as you can see because Upgrade 1 & Upgrade 2 were sent Consecutively, it groups them together. The "Action" table is a reference, and should be used for the consecutive grouping as well as the postid & posttype.

I looked around on SO but didnt see anything quite like mine. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's another version that works with MySQL Variables and doesn't require 3 level nesting deep.  The first one pre-sorts the records in order by postID and Date and assigns them a sequential number per group whenever any time a value changes in one of the Post ID, Type and/or action.  From that, Its a simple group by... no comparing record version T to T2 to T3... what if you wanted 4 or 5 criteria... would you have to nest even more entries?, or just add 2 more @sql variables to the comparison test...

Your call on which is more efficient...

```
select
      PreQuery.postID,
      PreQuery.PostType,
      PreQuery.Target,
      PreQuery.Action,
      PreQuery.Title,
      min( PreQuery.Date ) as FirstActionDate,
      max( PreQuery.Date ) as LastActionDate,
      count(*) as ActionEntries,
      group_concat( PreQuery.content ) as Content
   from
      ( select
              t.*,
              @lastSeq := if( t.action = @lastAction
                          AND t.postID = @lastPostID
                          AND t.postType = @lastPostType, @lastSeq, @lastSeq +1 ) as ActionSeq,
              @lastAction := t.action,
              @lastPostID := t.postID,
              @lastPostType := t.PostType
           from
              t,
              ( select @lastAction := ' ',
                       @lastPostID := 0,
                       @lastPostType := ' ',
                       @lastSeq := 0 ) sqlVars
           order by
              t.postid,
              t.date ) PreQuery
   group by
      PreQuery.postID,
      PreQuery.ActionSeq,
      PreQuery.PostType,
      PreQuery.Action
```

Here's my [link to SQLFiddle sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bd385/7)

For the title, you might want to adjust the line...

group_concat( distinct PreQuery.Title ) as Titles,

At least this will give DISTINCT titles concatinated... much tougher to get let without nesting this entire query one more level by having the max query date and other elements to get the one title associated with that max date per all criteria.

Comment: Your code does seem to be significantly faster! What would you recommend for getting the last title without creating another subquery: (SELECT t2.title FROM t2 WHERE t2.id = MAX(t.id))?

Answer (score 1):

There is no primary key in your table so for my example I used `date`. You should create an auto increment value and use that instead of the `date` in my example.

This is a solution ([view on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c444f/11)):

```
SELECT 
  postid,
  posttype,
  target,
  action,
  COALESCE((
    SELECT date
    FROM t t2
    WHERE t2.postid = t.postid
    AND t2.posttype = t.posttype
    AND t2.action = t.action
    AND t2.date > t.date
    AND NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT TRUE
      FROM t t3
      WHERE t3.date > t.date
      AND t3.date < t2.date
      AND (t3.postid != t.postid OR t3.posttype != t.posttype OR t3.action != t.action)
    )
  ), t.date) AS group_criterion,
  MAX(title),
  GROUP_CONCAT(content)
FROM t
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5
ORDER BY group_criterion
```

It basically reads:

> For each row create a group criterion and in the end group by it.
>   This criterion is the highest `date` of the rows *following the current one* and having the same postid, posttype and action as the current one but there may be not a row of different postid, posttype or action between them.
>   In other words, the group criterion is the highest occurring date in a group of consecutive entries.

If you use proper indexes it shouldn't be terribly slow but if you have a lot of rows you should think of caching this information.

Comment: I'm sorry, I only posted the fields I thought were relevant to the query.


The full table is: id,group,postid,posttype,action,target,date, title,content,link,published


(id being the primary key)

Comment: You are talking about grouping consecutive entries and you think an auto increment primary key is not relevant to the query? Quite audicious. ;)

Comment: You're right lol, I'm not sure what I was thinking, when I even tried it myself I was trying to use the ID. I need a coffee! I might have another question about this shortly. Thank you!

Comment: Sofar everything seems to be working, I am having a bit of an issue with MAX(title) not returning the correct title. It returns a title with "W" first, which leads me to believe it is going by alphabetical order?

Comment: Yes it does... choose whatever aggregate function you like or leave it out althogher. You didn't specify any requirement about that.

Comment: I hope that before judging the performance of my query you made sure to have an index on `date` and one on `postid, posttype, action, date`, right?

Comment: I double checked and did need to add an index (I also removed the "date" from your query and changed it to "id" as you recommended in the post, don't know if this matters) - With your query I get about 0.0633 and with the other query I get 0.0070. Not sure if i did something else wrong.

Comment: Yes, then you need `id` instead of `date` in the two indexes. But yeah, a difference like that is certainly possible if you have a decent number of rows.