# MySQL query for consecutive identical results

Tags: mysql

```
table-1
+-----+----------+--------+----------+---------------------+
| id  | isp_name | uptime | downtime | stamp_date          |
+-----+----------+--------+----------+---------------------+
| 581 | AIRCEL   |      0 |      289 | 2015-01-23 10:27:26 |
| 584 | AIRCEL   |    310 |        0 | 2015-01-23 10:32:27 |
| 587 | AIRCEL   |      0 |      297 | 2015-01-23 10:37:28 |
| 590 | AIRCEL   |      0 |      303 | 2015-01-23 10:42:29 |
| 593 | AIRCEL   |      0 |      311 | 2015-01-23 10:47:30 |
| 596 | AIRCEL   |    272 |        0 | 2015-01-23 10:52:31 |
| 599 | AIRCEL   |    300 |        0 | 2015-01-23 10:57:32 |
| 602 | AIRCEL   |      0 |      317 | 2015-01-23 11:02:33 |
| 605 | AIRCEL   |      0 |      287 | 2015-01-23 11:07:34 |
| 608 | AIRCEL   |    317 |        0 | 2015-01-23 11:12:35 |
| 611 | AIRCEL   |    292 |        0 | 2015-01-23 11:17:36 |
| 614 | AIRCEL   |      0 |      292 | 2015-01-23 11:22:37 |
+-----+----------+--------+----------+---------------------+
```

Hi the above is my uptime and downtime results.

I want to display the consecutive downtime records only like below table.

```
table-2
+----------+--------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| isp_name | uptime | downtime | start_time          | end_time            |
+----------+--------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| AIRCEL   |      0 |      289 | 2015-01-23 10:27:26 | 2015-01-23 10:32:28 |
| AIRCEL   |      0 |      297 | 2015-01-23 10:37:28 | 2015-01-23 10:52:31 |
| AIRCEL   |      0 |      317 | 2015-01-23 11:02:33 | 2015-01-23 11:12:35 |
| AIRCEL   |      0 |      292 | 2015-01-23 11:22:37 | NOW                 |
 +----------+-------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+




    SELECT isp_name,
       interface_up_time AS uptime,
       interface_down_time AS downtime,
       min(stamp_date) AS start_time,
       max(stamp_date) AS end_time
FROM
  (SELECT r.*,
          (@ups := @ups + (interface_up_time = 0)) AS ups,
          (@downs := @downs + (interface_up_time != 0)) AS downs
   FROM interface_stats r
   CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @ups := 0, @downs := 0) vars
   WHERE isp_name='AIRCEL'
     AND device_id='fmpvd2001100999'
     AND stamp_date >='2015-01-23 10:23:10'
     AND stamp_date <='2015-01-23 11:23:10'
   ORDER BY stamp_date) r
GROUP BY interface_up_time, (CASE
                                 WHEN interface_up_time = 0 THEN downs
                                 ELSE ups
                             END);
```

I have tried the above query and obtained the result like

```
table-3
+----------+--------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
 | isp_name | uptime | downtime | start_time          | end_time           |
+----------+--------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| AIRCEL   |      0 |      289 | 2015-01-23 10:27:26 | 2015-01-23 10:27:26 |
| AIRCEL   |      0 |      297 | 2015-01-23 10:37:28 | 2015-01-23 10:47:30 |
| AIRCEL   |      0 |      317 | 2015-01-23 11:02:33 | 2015-01-23 11:07:34 |
| AIRCEL   |      0 |      292 | 2015-01-23 11:22:37 | 2015-01-23 11:22:37 |
| AIRCEL   |    272 |        0 | 2015-01-23 10:52:31 | 2015-01-23 10:52:31 |
| AIRCEL   |    292 |        0 | 2015-01-23 11:17:36 | 2015-01-23 11:17:36 |
| AIRCEL   |    300 |        0 | 2015-01-23 10:57:32 | 2015-01-23 10:57:32 |
| AIRCEL   |    310 |        0 | 2015-01-23 10:32:27 | 2015-01-23 10:32:27 |
| AIRCEL   |    317 |        0 | 2015-01-23 11:12:35 | 2015-01-23 11:12:35 |
+----------+--------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Could you please anyone help me to achieve the results?.

Comment: @David, table-1 is my actual table values . I have tried the above query and got the table-3 as result. table-2 is my expected result.I refered the above query from [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27925433/mysql-return-first-and-last-record-for-consecutive-identical-results)

Comment: It's not clear the algorithm to get the table-2. I.e. Why AIRCEL 0 - 297 have those start / end time? Why 303 downtime is discarded in your result?

Comment: @Joe taras, the link AIRCEL goes down at 2015-01-23 10:37:28 and becomes active at 2015-01-23 10:52:31. Till this duration the uptime is 0.so i would like the downtime duration to be printed as 2015-01-23 10:37:28  to 2015-01-23 10:52:30. (1 second prior to the link become active).

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way. This gets all results. If you only want downtimes, just amend the final WHERE clause accordingly.

```
SELECT a.isp_name
     , a.status
     , a.duration
     , a.stamp_date start
     , MIN(c.stamp_date) end 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT isp_name
            , CASE WHEN uptime > 0 THEN 'up' ELSE 'down' END status
            , CASE WHEN uptime > 0 THEN uptime ELSE downtime END duration
            , stamp_date
            , @a := @a + 1 seq
         FROM my_table
         JOIN (SELECT @a:=0) vars
     ) a
  LEFT 
  JOIN  
     ( SELECT isp_name
            , CASE WHEN uptime > 0 THEN 'up' ELSE 'down' END status
            , CASE WHEN uptime > 0 THEN uptime ELSE downtime END duration
            , stamp_date
            , @b := @b + 1 seq
         FROM my_table
         JOIN (SELECT @b:=0) vars
     ) b 
    ON b.seq = a.seq - 1
   AND b.isp_name = a.isp_name
   AND b.status = a.status
  LEFT 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT isp_name
            , CASE WHEN uptime > 0 THEN 'up' ELSE 'down' END status
            , CASE WHEN uptime > 0 THEN uptime ELSE downtime END duration
            , stamp_date
            , @c := @c + 1 seq
         FROM my_table
         JOIN (SELECT @c:=0) vars
     ) c 
    ON c.seq >= a.seq
   AND c.isp_name = a.isp_name
   AND c.status = a.status
  LEFT 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT isp_name
            , CASE WHEN uptime > 0 THEN 'up' ELSE 'down' END status
            , CASE WHEN uptime > 0 THEN uptime ELSE downtime END duration
            , stamp_date
            , @d := @d + 1 seq
         FROM my_table
         JOIN (SELECT @d:=0) vars
     ) d 
    ON d.seq = c.seq + 1
   AND d.isp_name = a.isp_name
   AND d.status = a.status
 WHERE b.seq IS NULL 
   AND c.seq IS NOT NULL
   AND d.seq IS NULL
 GROUP 
    BY a.seq;
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this may be what you're looking for, although I've only tested in SQL Server as I don't have MySQL handy, but should work the same...

```
SELECT MIN(isp_name) AS isp_name, 
       MIN(uptime) AS uptime, 
       MIN(downtime) AS downtime,
       MIN(start_time) AS start_time,
       end_time FROM

       (SELECT d.isp_name, 
            d.uptime, 
            d.downtime, 
            d.stamp_date AS start_time, 
            COALESCE((SELECT MIN(CAST(u.stamp_date AS VARCHAR(20))) 
                FROM table-1 u 
                WHERE u.stamp_date > d.stamp_date 
                    AND u.uptime > 0), 'NOW') AS end_time 

            FROM table-1 d 
            WHERE d.downtime > 0) down

       GROUP BY end_time;
```

The only problem is the casting of u.stamp_date to VARCHAR seems to convert the `end_time` to "human readable" format, which I had to do to display "NOW" instead of "NULL" - I'm sure if there's a way around that you can find it somewhere on stackoverflow... OTOH you might be happy just displaying "NULL".... or maybe in MySQL you don't need to cast it...

You could use `ISNULL` instead of `COALESCE` and I think it should get the same result.

Comment: @colmde.Thanks.I have changed you sql like "SELECT id,d.isp_name, d.interface_up_time, d.interface_down_time, d.stamp_date AS start_time, COALESCE((SELECT MIN(CAST(u.stamp_date AS DATETIME)) FROM interface_stats u WHERE u.stamp_date > d.stamp_date AND u.interface_up_time > 0), 'NOW') AS end_time FROM interface_stats d WHERE d.interface_down_time > 0 and isp_name='AIRCEL' and device_id='fmpvd2001100999' and stamp_date   >='2015-01-23 10:23:10' and stamp_date <='2015-01-23 11:23:10' GROUP BY end_time;" and its got matched with my expectation.

Comment: I took only inner part of your sql and Mysql CAST() doesn't support for VARCHAR so i changed that into DATETIME.thanks a lot

Comment: No problem - you may be better off only taking the inner part - I could not do that on SQL server but looks like MySQL allows it - and I just spotted a mistake with all those `MIN(...)` statements at the beginning

Comment: Though I have to ask, if it helped, why the downvote?