# SQL query to calculate uptime of application

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an application that logs information like connections and disconnections in the same table. I would like to try and calculate the total application uptime.

The table structure is like this

```
status     time 
connect    2015-09-28 12:05:45.783
disconnect 2015-09-28 12:09:45.783
connect    2015-09-28 12:35:15.783
disconnect 2015-09-28 14:45:35.783
```

EDIT:

How would I write a query to calculate this? I was trying to use the total time, some thing like this

```
/*
status     time 
connect    2015-09-28 12:05:45.783
disconnect 2015-09-28 12:09:45.783
connect    2015-09-28 12:35:15.783
disconnect 2015-09-28 14:45:35.783
*/
declare @0 datetime;
set @0 = '2015-09-28 12:00:0.000'

declare @1 datetime;
set @1 = '2015-09-28 12:05:45.783'

declare @2 datetime;
set @2 =  '2015-09-28 12:09:45.783'

declare @3 datetime;
set @3 =  '2015-09-28 12:35:45.783'

declare @4 datetime;
set @4 = '2015-09-28 14:45:45.783'

select DATEDIFF(MS, @1, @3)
select DATEDIFF(MS, @2, @4)
```

Comment: What is your current query, and what error are you getting?

Comment: It seems you haven't thought much about the problem, yet. The first step would be to find the matching disconnect for each connect, right? Then think about what to do in case of data inconsistency (two connects or two disconnects following each other).

Comment: Shouldn't you be looking at the DATEDIFFs between 1 & 2  and 3 & 4 instead?    Why 1-3 and 2-4?

Comment: Following up on Tabs question: Are there only 4 entries each time? Where does the output have to go? Please [edit] your question, insert all relevant info.

Comment: The following similar question may be useful to you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27925433/mysql-return-first-and-last-record-for-consecutive-identical-results

Answer (score 4):

Using a common table expression, you can arrange your status history into a view with a start time and end time for each record, like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/18438/1

```
with t1 (stat, ts, ndx) as (
  select stat, ts, row_number() over(order by ts)
  from connected
)
,
t2 (stat, startts, endts) as (
  select t1.stat, t1.ts, coalesce(t2.ts, getdate())
  from t1
  left join t1 t2
  on t2.ndx = t1.ndx + 1
)
select * from t2
order by startts
```

I used the `coalesce(t2.ts, getdate())` to get the current date time for the last record in your range.

If you want to find the amount of time that each status was held, use the `datediff()` function, like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/18438/2

```
with t1 (stat, ts, ndx) as (
  select stat, ts, row_number() over(order by ts)
  from connected
)
,
t2 (stat, startts, endts) as (
  select t1.stat, t1.ts, coalesce(t2.ts, getdate())
  from t1
  left join t1 t2
  on t2.ndx = t1.ndx + 1
)
select stat, startts, endts, datediff(second, startts, endts) as elapsed
from t2
order by startts
```

And if you want total up and down time, that's just math and formatting: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e90a3/33

```
with t1 (stat, ts, ndx) as (
  select stat, ts, row_number() over(order by ts)
  from connected
)
,
t2 (stat, startts, endts) as (
  select t1.stat, t1.ts, coalesce(t2.ts, getdate())
  from t1
  left join t1 t2
  on t2.ndx = t1.ndx + 1
)
,
t3 (stat, totaltime) as (
  select stat, sum(datediff(second, startts, endts))
  from t2
  group by stat
)
select stat,
  cast(totaltime / 86400 as varchar) + ' ' + 
  right('0' + cast((totaltime % 86400) / 3600 as varchar),2) + ':' +
  right('0' + cast((totaltime % 3600) / 60 as varchar),2)  + ':' +
  right('0' + cast(totaltime % 60 as varchar),2)
  as [Days HH:MM:SS]
from t3
```

Comment: EDIT: I've made a change so that the display in HH:MM:SS now includes days. The other option also wasn't letting the minutes turn to hours (at 60 minutes) or the hours turn to days (at 24 hours).

Answer (score 2):

This question seems to be abandoned. However in order to help future readers with a similar problem, here is how to approach it:

The table contains alternating records: connect, disconnect, connect, disconnect, etc. We can use `LAG` to look into a previous row. Doing so, we only have to take the disconnect records then with their previous records' time, which is their connect time of course.

Only, it's important, to *first* get the previous times and *then* filter for 'disconnect'. If we would filter directly with `WHERE status = 'disconnect`, then `LAG` would give us the previous *disconnect* record's time, of course. So we first write the inner lag query, then use this to filter the desired records outside.

```
select sum(time_used) as total_seconds
from
(
  select 
    datediff(second, log_time, lag(log_time) over (order by log_time)) as time_used,
    status
  from connection_logs
) times_used
where status = 'disconnect';
```

SQL fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dfba6a/1

We should usually also think about the case of a missing connect or disconnect record, so we'd have two consecutive connects or disconnects. One solution would be to ignore the record with the missing partner, so we'd look at `lag(status)` and only use it if that status really is 'connect':

```
select sum(time_used) as total_seconds
from
(
  select 
    datediff(second, log_time, lag(log_time) over (order by log_time)) as time_used,
    status,
    lag(status) over (order by log_time) as previous_status
  from connection_logs
) times_used
where status = 'disconnect'
and previous_status = 'connect';
```

SQL fiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dfba6a/2

Answer (score 0):

this is quick and dirt but it works - using a common table expression (cte):

```
;WITH cte
AS
(SELECT t.statustext, logtime, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY statustext ORDER BY logtime) AS id
FROM    dbo.NameOfYourTable t
)

SELECT  con.logtime AS LoginTime, 
        discon.logtime AS LogoutTime, 
        DATEDIFF(MINUTE,con.logtime,discon.logtime) AS SessionTimeInMinutes
FROM    cte AS con
        INNER JOIN cte AS discon ON con.id = discon.id
WHERE   con.statustext = 'connect'
        AND discon.statustext = 'disconnect'
```

Note: for my example i changed column names to statustext and logtime. `status`and `time`are SQL Keywords and should not be used as column names!