# Get the fruit order from the fruit table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the order once from the fruit table even if the `fruit_name` exists before so if I have this scenario:

1. Apple
2. Apple
3. Orange
4. Orange
5. Orange
6. Apple
7. Apple

I want to get this order: `Apple, Orange, Apple`

or if I have the following:

1. Apple
2. Apple
3. Orange
4. Orange
5. Orange
6. Strawberry
7. Strawberry
8. Strawberry

I want to get `Apple, Orange, Strawberry`

I have tried this query but it does not work for the first scenario.

`select distinct fruit_name  FROM fruit where  ORDER BY fruit_id  ASC`

How can I get it?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Ofcourse its not going to work https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html

Comment: For starters, Orange and Orang will show up separately.

Comment: In SQL, you should never rely on getting results in any particular order unless you can express that order an ORDER BY clause. Tables are just sets of tuples and sets are unordered.

Comment: Solved. Similar question [check this][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13317206/mysql-group-by-consecutive-rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on my comment - since rows are unordered in SQL, I'll assume the table has two columns: ID and Name. This assumes that IDs are consecutive - see Sami's answer for the case where the IDs are ordered but not necessarily consecutive. Given that, something like this would be well-defined:

```
select ID, Name
from Fruit F1
where F1.ID + 1 not in (
    select ID
    from Fruit F2
    where F1.Name = F2.Name
) order by ID Asc
```

This works by selecting all fruit names such that the following fruit name is not the same as the current one. By definition, we always pick the last row in a run of rows with the same name (since the row after the run will have a different fruit name, it will satisfy the WHERE clause). Given this:

```
1 Apple
2 Apple
3 Orange
4 Orange
5 Orange
6 Apple
7 Apple
```

You would expect this as output:

```
2 Apple
5 Orange
7 Apple
```

Comment: This assumes that IDs are consecutive, that might be good to mention. My answer will only assume they are in order.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are talking about grouping your results. You can group your results so there will be always only one result per fruit. But if you are grouping by name, you cannot have *Apple* shown twice - only once (see below how to achieve two *Apple* results). Also, I guess that *Orang* is a typo and it should be *Orange* aswell.

This selects *Apple, Orange, Strawberry*:

```
SELECT fruit_name FROM fruit GROUP BY name ORDER BY name
```

Also, if you want different order, you can just change the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT fruit_name FROM fruit GROUP BY name ORDER BY name = 'Orange' DESC, name
```

Query above selects *Orange, Apple, Strawberry*

If structure of your table is more complex, you could also achieve getting 2 *Apple* results. You just need to use another column to group by, for example something like *apple_type*:

```
SELECT fruit_name FROM fruit GROUP BY fruit_name, apple_type
```

Remember: In some databases like Oracle, you cannot select columns that are not in `GROUP BY` clause or one of aggregate functions, like *SUM()*.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a table with a running id for ordering, it is possible to do. Let's assume there is a table `data` with column `id` for ordering and `name` for the fruit:

```
SELECT name FROM (
  SELECT id, name, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM data d
    WHERE d.name<>data.name AND d.id<=data.id) as t
  FROM data) x
GROUP BY name, t ORDER BY MIN(id)
```

This will first count how many of the other values are before these values, essentially making groupings. Then when we group by the fruit and the count we can distinguish between the actual groups. Ordering by `MIN(id)` makes sure you get them in the correct order since the database could return them however it wants otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can just execute a simple query like the following :

```
select distinct(fruit_name) from fruit_table order by fruit_name;
```