# How do I group rows in mysql table till the value changes? (without using variables)

Tags: mysql

I have a table with name 'employees', I want to group the rows by their designation only till it changes.

please look at the **sample table**.

```
Id  Name    Designation     Employee Id Last Modified   
1   John    General Manager     1       15-10-2001  
2   John    General Manager     1       05-11-2001  
3   John    Product Manager     1       06-11-2001  
4   John    Product Manager     1       15-11-2001  
5   John    General Manager     1       30-12-2001
```

**Expected Output**

```
Employee Id Name    Designation     Valid From  Valid to
1           John    General Manager 15-10-2001  05-11-2001
1           John    Product Manager 06-11-2001  15-12-2001
1           John    General Manger  16-12-2001  30-12-2001
```

I tried using group by clause, but it is giving me only 2 rows (General Manager, Product Manager).
But I want an output as shown in the table from which I can solve a bigger problem that involves starting date and ending date for each role.
Thanks in advance!.

Comment: Don't _"SS"_ , post the data in textual form. That's much easier for anyone to copy & paste if they want to help you.

Comment: Please look at the edit, I have changed it to textual form. Hope it helps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL Group By Consecutive Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13317206/mysql-group-by-consecutive-rows)

Comment: Yes, it should work. But I need the solution without using variables. Is the possible?

Comment: What is your version of mysql?

Comment: 8.0 is the version that Im currently using in my local

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+gaps+and+islands

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
WITH cte1 AS(
  SELECT EmployeeId, 
        LastModified,
        Designation,
        LEAD(Designation) OVER (ORDER BY EmployeeId, LastModified) AS NextDesg,
        LAG(LastModified) OVER (ORDER BY EmployeeId, LastModified) AS PrevLm
   FROM mytable),
  cte2 AS (
SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER()
           OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeId ORDER BY LastModified) AS NewGroup
  FROM cte1
WHERE (Designation != NextDesg OR NextDesg IS NULL)
  ORDER BY LastModified) 
  
SELECT t.EmployeeId, t.Name, t.Designation, 
       MIN(t.LastModified) AS "Valid From", 
       MAX(t.LastModified) AS "Valid To",
       COALESCE(c1.NewGroup, c2.NewGroup) AS NwGr
  FROM mytable t
  LEFT JOIN cte2 c1 
ON t.EmployeeId=c1.EmployeeId
 AND t.LastModified=c1.LastModified
 LEFT JOIN cte2 c2
ON t.EmployeeId=c2.EmployeeId
 AND t.LastModified=c2.PrevLm
  GROUP BY t.EmployeeId, t.Name, t.Designation, NwGr;
```

The main idea here is to assign each set as a new group, then use that to group by the results.

We start by doing common table expression twice. The first one is:

```
WITH cte1 AS(
  SELECT EmployeeId, 
        LastModified,
        Designation,
        LEAD(Designation) OVER (ORDER BY EmployeeId, LastModified) AS NextDesg,
        LAG(LastModified) OVER (ORDER BY EmployeeId, LastModified) AS PrevLm
   FROM mytable)
```

I'm using `LEAD()` to get the next `Designation` value to be used as a delimiter and `LAG()` to get the previous `LastModified` value to be used in `ON` for the second `LEFT JOIN` in the final query.

The second `cte`:

```
cte2 AS (
SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER()
           OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeId ORDER BY LastModified) AS NewGroup
  FROM cte1
WHERE (Designation != NextDesg OR NextDesg IS NULL)
  ORDER BY LastModified)
```

Here is where I used the value returned using `LEAD()` the first `cte` to identify the change in `Designation` then I add `ROW_NUMBER()` function to generate as `NewGroup`.

Then in the final query:

```
...
FROM mytable t
  LEFT JOIN cte2 c1 
ON t.EmployeeId=c1.EmployeeId
 AND t.LastModified=c1.LastModified
 LEFT JOIN cte2 c2
ON t.EmployeeId=c2.EmployeeId
 AND t.LastModified=c2.PrevLm
...
```

I did `LEFT JOIN` from the main table with `cte2` twice, the first one is matching by `EmployeeId` and `LastModified` of both and the second one is matching by `EmployeeID` and the previous `LastModified` value obtained from the `LAG()` function.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/YgWSViAG)